# Constantly updating numbers

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I want to create a number on the page that says something like `1,299,282 images viewed`. The number `1,299,282` will be grabbed from the database table as the largest number in the auto-incrementing column `id` using `select max(id) from listings`

This number does not need to update AJAX style without reloading the page, but will ideally change on page reload if the max `id` did indeed get larger.

Is there a way to cache this, as the number only changes every 10 minutes. Or will caching this be too much work?

Comment: Whether or not you should cache this depends on the ratio between the number of page loads and the number of updates (and the relative cost of each).

Comment: a select max(id) isn't going to be much overhead. but writing the number out ot a file or other caching mechanism will likely cost as much to write it as it would save anything. you only cache things that have HIGH generation costs and LOW retrieval COSTS. a single number is usually not a good candidate, especially when it's a trivial operation to retrieve

Comment: It is my opinion that the piece of code that updates the database should take care for updating this number or caching it! so when some page loads, it will not have to access the database, just will check the cached value.

Comment: +1 Marc, that's a good point.

Comment: Melsi, tight coupling of systems is often a bad thing. Suppose you need to swap out databases, or the caching backend. You do not want these separate things to be coupled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using loop for this. Just use it simple.

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(`ID`) FROM `LISTINGS`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$mynumber = $row['ID'];

echo $mynumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

if your only doing it on a page reload just do this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `LISTINGS` ORDER BY `ID` Desc Limit 1;";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $mynumber = $row['ID'];
}

echo $mynumber;
```

This will give you the largest ID number in the database. And if it goes up, it will show it when the page is reloaded and the script is run again.

Edit: no need to cache really, as this is a pretty lightweight script.

Comment: Why order and limit instead of selecting Max(id)?

Comment: i guess max(id) would be a bit more appropriate, this is just how ive done it on the past.

Answer (score 0):

About the cache part, see [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10397975/922143) to the [Meta Cache or CodeIgniter Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395235/meta-cache-or-codeigniter-cache/10397975) question.